# Selenium doesn't click on the top-most element

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Consider the following Selenium automation:
Its goal is to go to a [financial chart from the website Barchart](https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/AAPL/interactive-chart), click on the custom calendar icon (at the top right corner over the chart), input a custom range in the form that pops up over it, and validated it using the apply button.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/AAPL/interactive-chart'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.calendar-icon').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('option[label="Intraday"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-ng-model="selectedAggregation.range.from"]').send_keys('11/01/2019')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-ng model="selectedAggregation.range.to"]').send_keys('11/01/2019')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-ng-model="selectedAggregation.range.to"]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-ng-click="modalConfirm()"]').click()
```

It works fine for the most part, until I try to validate, which never works. I then realised that sometime this last action would lead me to a promotional page whose link is located exactly beneath the Apply button. Which seems to indicate that selenium 'click through' the form onto the link below.

I have tried other selector for the apply button, which all give the same result.
I also try to use the `submit()` method from selenium, which returns an error. Lastly, I also try to implement the `execute_script` method from selenium, but I did not manage to understand what exactly is the javascript call being executed on clicking apply.

Note : this is because i need to get the cookie and xsrf token that is generated by that call, not because i need to collect the actual financial data ( I know that the financial data can be collected using `'https://www.barchart.com/proxies/timeseries/queryminutes.ashx?' + data`), where `data` are the query string parameters.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look for you, the below should accept the changes for you, I've checked this and it works for me.

```
javascript = 'document.querySelector("body > div.reveal-modal.fade.interactive-chart-modal-aggregation.in > div > div > div > button.bc-button.light-blue").click()'

driver.execute_script(javascript)
```

Comment: If you wanted to know how: right click the element in chrome and inspect, within the inspect window, go to copy and select "Copy JS Path", paste that along with the ".click()" function and you get the above.

Comment: Also, the problem probably stemmed from using a css selector that wasn't unique on the page. When there are multiple elements selected by the same CSS selector, selenium chooses the earliest one in the DOM.